# wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory [ Closed ]

Tags: node.js, meteor, wkhtmltopdf

I installed wkhtmltopdf from the following code

```
sudo apt-get install wkhtmltopdf
```

But when I am creating PDF then it is generating following error

```
Error: /bin/bash: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 8):

I think the correct path would be `/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf`. You can get it by `which wkhtmltopdf` command.

Comment: Thanks! next I added a symlink ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf

Answer (score 3):

It appears that when you're trying to run wkhtmltopdf, it's not finding the program to execute.

You can try to locate it with `locate wkhtmltopdf`. That should return the path to the executable. If that doesn't return a path, you can use this (but it will take longer): `find / -name wkhtmltopdf 2>/dev/null`.

Once you've got the path of the executable, make sure to add it to your $PATH, so it can be called from anywhere on the command line. See [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26059) for instructions on how to add to the path variable.

Comment: Right now it showing following error:

Error: /bin/bash: wkhtmltopdf: command not found

Answer (score 2):

After a long time facing this issue I decided to replace it by another converter.

I removed `wkhtmltopdf` and I installed [html-pdf](https://github.com/marcbachmann/node-html-pdf) converter and then PDF file created successfullu

Comment: I am just about to do this as well, wkhtmltopdf is pissing me off, been fighting with it for days

Comment: I am face same problem but not wkhtmltopdf its wkhtmltoimage