# Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf": error=2, No such file or directory - Getting this error from Java

Tags: java, wkhtmltopdf

I am executing wkhtmltopdf command line tool from Java but it is throwing below error.

```
Cannot run program "wkhtmltopdf": error=2, No such file or directory
```

But note that when I execute this command line tool from my mac terminal then pdf got generated successfully. Please see below.

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ inDiscover$ wkhtmltopdf /var/folders/7y/2vr28n113p908ksnk0fnpqch0000gn/T/test7896850081571855407.html /Users/mymac/Documents/Project/emailbody/test2.pdf
Loading pages (1/6)
Counting pages (2/6)                                               
Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
Done
```

I have seen lot many similar questions here (for ex: [wkhtmltopdf: No such file or directory [ Closed ]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627142/wkhtmltopdf-no-such-file-or-directory-closed)) but issue with those questions are related to `$PATH`. In my case I believe that I have set the path to the executable to `$PATH` correctly. Please see below.

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ inDiscover$ locate wkhtmltopdf
/private/var/db/receipts/org.wkhtmltopdf.wkhtmltox.bom
/private/var/db/receipts/org.wkhtmltopdf.wkhtmltox.plist
/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf
/usr/local/share/man/man1/wkhtmltopdf.1.gz
```

You can see here `wkhtmltopdf` has been added to `$PATH` (/usr/local/bin)

Also , see below the response for `echo $PATH`.

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ inDiscover$ echo $PATH
/Users/mymac/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
MacBook-Air-2:~ inDiscover$
```

I am getting this issue only when I try to execute the command from Java. Please see my java code below.

```
String VIEWPORT_SIZE = "2480x3508";
        int CONVERSION_DPI = 300;
        int IMAGE_QUALITY = 100;
        
        List<String> cmd = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("wkhtmltopdf",
                "--viewport-size", VIEWPORT_SIZE,
                "--enable-local-file-access",
                // "--disable-smart-shrinking",
                "--dpi", String.valueOf(CONVERSION_DPI),
                "--image-quality", String.valueOf(IMAGE_QUALITY)));
        //cmd.addAll(extParams);
        cmd.add("/var/folders/7y/2vr28n113p908ksnk0fnpqch0000gn/T/test7896850081571855407.html");
        cmd.add("/Users/mymac/Documents/Project/emailbody/test3.pdf");
        
        
        try {
            ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(cmd);

            if (Logger.level.compareTo(LogLevel.Info) >= 0) {
                pb.inheritIO();
            }

            Process p = pb.start();
            p.waitFor();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Am I really missing something?

Comment: Trying with an absolute path may help pinpoint the problem. It seems `pb.environment()` could also give you some useful info on the paths actually used in the java version.

Comment: These are the paths returned - PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin. And my webhtmltopdf is in /usr/local/bin which is not in the returned list. But as I mentioned in my question /usr/local/bin is also $PATH. So wondering why it is not considering this path.

Comment: By the paths you get my first bet would be that you are running the java program as a different user. I managed to get a shorter list of path on linux using sudo (It still had usr/bin/local, but this could be os/system specific). Otherwise it coud be something mac-related and I can't help with that.

Comment: I checked the user using System.getProperty("user.name"); which returns the same user as in my Mac Terminal. And from Terminal I am able to run the program successfully.

Comment: The path / env inside your shell could wholly different to the one Java is using - depends on the launcher. You might get expected results if changing the command to run your shell first so your environment matches your interactive shell example - such as {"/bin/bash", -c", "wkhtmltopdf", ...}. But as as @Harpistry says it would be easier to try call with absolute path.

Comment: @DuncG , I am trying to understand this. So I need to run any bash script to match my Mac OS environment with Java environment??. If my understanding is wrong can you please explain me what exactly you meant to say.

Comment: Sorry I didn't mean add any shell, but the exact same shell you use interactively. If adding the shell works then some part of the shell profile setup is doing something that you can compare with whatever way you run your java app, and may help understand the difference. Example do you have alias or extra path var set in .bashrc. Is your java app run from same shell after reading same profile?

Comment: Also check print path inside the java app before ProcessBuilder: `System.out.println("PATH="+System.getenv("PATH"));`

Comment: System.getenv() returns /usr/bin , /usr/sbin , /sbin.  But I did not understand your comment - "compare with whatever way you run your java app, and may help understand the difference". Here compare what and what?. Since I am not good in shell I really appreciate if you could provide step by step details of what I can do to find the difference.

Also , I tried to create symlink to the executable path but my mac os (Sierra , version 10.12.6) does not permit me for any such operation.

Comment: Please see below response from Terminal.

MacBook-Air-2:bin inDiscover$ sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf /usr/bin
ln: /usr/bin/wkhtmltopdf: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few things you can check, one will hopefully resolve your issue.

Nearly all occasions I've seen where java is not finding an application that your shell or terminal does run are down to use of commands built into the shell / terminal (such as an alias), or because of PATH used in a script that you use to launch your `java yourapp.ClassName ...` is different to that set for the interactive shell / terminal.

The interactive shell / terminal may include or source from other scripts on startup - for example it may have run code in `~/.bashrc`, `~/.login`, `~/.profile`, ... meaning that PATH declared inside interactive shell is not same as PATH presented to Java app when you launched it.

Hence you see terminal show PATH has /usr/local/bin:

```
MacBook-Air-2:~ inDiscover$ echo $PATH
/Users/mymac/anaconda/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

But Java says no /usr/local/bin in PATH:

```
System.out.println("PATH="+System.getenv("PATH"));
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

So to fix your problem you could make java use absolute path to run the app wkhtmltopdf:

```
Arrays.asList("wkhtmltopdf" ->  Arrays.asList("/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf" ...
```

OR you could make java launch your shell / terminal so the terminal sources its env scripts as normal and runs the command:

```
# Confirm which shell your Terminal uses:
echo $SHELL
```

If you have say `SHELL=/bin/bash` you can run `/bin/bash` from java and let it work out where wkhtmltopdf is:

```
Arrays.asList("wkhtmltopdf" ->  Arrays.asList("/bin/bash", "-c", "wkhtmltopdf" ...
```

OR if you have a script say `runMyApp.sh` to launch your java app, set the PATH before `java yourclass.Name`,

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
java yourclass.Name
```

OR if you have a script say `runMyApp.sh` to launch your java app, make that it sources the same profile environment as your Terminal does. This depends on the SHELL but for some systems could be something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Load env from current user - "source" and "." may or may not work in the SHELL you are using:
source ~/.bashrc
# OR maybe other shell
. ~/.somefilerc

echo $PATH # Now hopefully includes same /usr/local/bin
java yourclass.Name
```

Comment: Thanks DuncG for your detailed explanation. I set the path /usr/local/bin in Eclipse (run->run configuration->environments) and then it is working fine now.

Answer (score -3):

Try to add sudo in the front of wkhtmltopdf.

Comment: I think it will print Permission denied if it is solvable by putting sudo in front